# GroupItem Update Expander Header when Property on Items Collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I show a summary of a int Property (Math.Max) of Items in a CollectionListView which is grouped. This can be done by ValueConverter which works fine, but whenever this Proptery of an underlaying item gets changed, the Expander.Header is not updated. If i manually subscribe each PropertyChanged event of each single item and fire the CollectionChangedEvent the whole view is updated and the expander states get lost. How can i achive what i want without code behind just with XAML?

```
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Assign To: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items, Converter{StaticResource PropertyCollectionConverter}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>       
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What i want is something like this (pseudo code):

```
StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Assign To: "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Max(t => t.MyIntProperty)}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Any tips how can i achive this?

Comment: Your code behind is broken?

Comment: No it is not broken but when fireing CollectionChanged event the whole grid is updated and all expand states (expanded/collapsed) gets lost.

Comment: Then why do you need a XAML only solution?

Comment: I thougth there Must be a XAML only solution, i will also use a code behind solution but i want just the GroupItem Header to get updated not the whole collection and aftrwards each Group Header.